# Laravel webmix JS compilation issue in order with Vue Component

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, compilation

I am facing issue in compiling js in order wise.
I would like to compile library or custom js first but issue is laravel webmix compile Vue component first instead of custom js.

So when I run the command `npm run dev`, it will merge all the js into single one in `public/js/app.js`

But it will add all the vue component first and then custom.js code. So I would like to compile custom.js code first and then vue component code.

> **app.js**

```
require('./bootstrap');
require('./custom');

window.Vue = require('vue');

Vue.component('example-component', require('./components/ExampleComponent.vue').default);
Vue.component('product-list', require('./components/ProductListComponent.vue').default);
Vue.component('cart', require('./components/CartComponent.vue').default);
```

> **webpack.mix.js**

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

Comment: This strikes me as a bit of an odd requirement since the order in which code appears in a webpack bundle should not matter since webpack includes inside the code should happen in the correct order anyway.

Comment: I want to add custom js which have different jquery library into it. So jquery library should be included first before use it's own function. For ex. I want to use slick slider so I need to include slick slider js first and then I can assign slick slider to the element.

Answer (score 1):

app.js

```
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

Vue.component('example-component', require('./components/ExampleComponent.vue').default);
Vue.component('product-list', require('./components/ProductListComponent.vue').default);
Vue.component('cart', require('./components/CartComponent.vue').default);
```

custom.js

```
require('./custom');

window.Vue = require('vue');

Vue.component('example-component', require('./components/ExampleComponent.vue').default);
Vue.component('product-list', require('./components/ProductListComponent.vue').default);
Vue.component('cart', require('./components/CartComponent.vue').default);
```

webpack.mix.js

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .js('resources/js/custom.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```